# How can I make an input placeholder dynamically move with cursor?

Tags: javascript, angular, placeholder

I have an input inside my form, it holds a value price of a product,
at the beginning the input text placeholder is '$':

```
<input [placeholder]="$"/>
```

Now when ever I write something I want the '$' letter of the place holder to move with the cursor but inside the place holder and not as a text, for example when I write 123 it will show it like this 123$, what I did is at each change inside the input I add the letter '$' at the end of the input text but that it's not practical, I want it the letter '$' to be as a placeholder in the background and not part of the actual price.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @isherwood what do you mean by 'non-standard'

Comment: What have you tried? SO requires that you show effort before asking a question, and "any help" is usually too broad.

Comment: @isherwood because in other version I use '€' which is located at right

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an input field (e.g. a sample value or a short description of the expected format).

The short hint is displayed in the input field before the user enters a value and disapear as soon as the user enters a value.

What you want to do is to format the value that can't be achived with placehoder.

I'll go with a directive allowing you to configure the currency to display and where to display it. Just like [TestMask Lib](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you'd create a filter (or a "pipe" in Angular 2 parlance). Your scope value can be modified in the view using a template without changing the original value.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the "$" symbol is not meant to be part of the text and is used for guidance for the user, wouldn't you be better of implement this as something like:

```
<label>$</label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter value in USD" />
```

This way the $ will remain constant in front of the entered value.

Comment: check the comment section, I some case I need the symbol to be at the right of the text.

Comment: Depending on what you are using to determine the placement of the currency indicator, you could just as easily "ng-if or ng-show" the <label> to the front or the back of the <input>

Comment: Labels should contain text that's useful to those with visual impairments (using assistive technology). They should indicate the purpose of the input. A decorator is a better approach.